# Node.js: Shall I use Vows or Expresso or NodeUnit or Zombie.js or All?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, node.js, integration-testing

What shall I use when developing a node.js application?

Comment: I am using expresso. But to be honest that is just a matter of preference. I would also to include zombie.js into my testing process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zombie.js is there to provide you a headless browser to work with.

It should work fine with NodeUnit or Vows.  Zombie.js uses Vows for its own tests.  NodeUnit can be set to output JUnit compatible XML to use with a Continuous Integration solution like Hudson.

Answer (score 1):

I am using vows because it has a watcher (which means tests automatically run) and it groks CoffeeScript.